# How to add Music in AS3 Android App

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I am a noob in Adobe Flash Action Script 3..

I want a music player (with start, pause buttons) code in AS3, I have imported the music in the library and I have added the following code

```
var qMySound:Sound = new mySound1();
qMySound.play(0, 9999);
```

mySound1 is the AS Linkage
and it works.

I made a stop button using the code snippet's code

```
button_7.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToStopAllSounds_6);

function fl_ClickToStopAllSounds_6(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
}
```

And it works too, but now i want to start it again, I tried to use this code:

```
button_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_28);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_28(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

The music AS3 code is in Frame 1 btw.

And that doesn't work.. so any ideas?

---

edit:
This is my code:

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var myTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
var lastPosition:Number = 0;
var mySound:Sound = new mySound1(0,999);
myChannel = mySound.play();
// here is to learn how to deal with volume as well (between 0 and 1)
myTransform.volume = .5;
// setting the SoundTransform instance to the myChannel object
myChannel.soundTransform = myTransform;

pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickPauseHandler, false, 0, true);
play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickPlayHandler, false, 0, true);

function onClickPauseHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // getting the current position of the sound
    lastPosition = myChannel.position;
    // stopping the current sound
    myChannel.stop();
}

function onClickPlayHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // playing from the saved position
    myChannel = mySound.play(0,999);
}
```

And this error pops out.

Line 8 | 1151: A conflict exists with definition of mySound in namespace internal.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the classes [SoundChannel](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundChannel.html)/[SoundTransform](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundTransform.html) to have more functionalities. When you stop all sounds using [SoundMixer.stopAll()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundMixer.html#stopAll()), you are not stopping that respective sound.

Follow some example code, that you guide you to achieve what you are expecting, plus, give you some extra knowledge about how to deal with sound.

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var myTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
var lastPosition:Number = 0;
mySound.load(new URLRequest('yourMp3FileName.mp3'));
myChannel = mySound.play();
// here is to learn how to deal with volume as well (between 0 and 1)
myTransform.volume = .5;
// setting the SoundTransform instance to the myChannel object
myChannel.soundTransform = myTransform;

pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickPauseHandler, false, 0, true);
play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickPlayHandler, false, 0, true);

function onClickPauseHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // getting the current position of the sound
    lastPosition = myChannel.position;
    // stopping the current sound
    myChannel.stop();
}

function onClickPlayHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // playing from the saved position
    myChannel = mySound.play(lastPosition);
}
```

Comment: I dont get it, so how do I make the respective buttons to do that?

Comment: The buttons are just example that I created to call the respective method. You have your buttons, button_7, button_1, that you can use, the buttons are not the essence of the answer, just to learn how to deal with sound.

Comment: Its saying Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error.
 at LetsChant_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[LetsChant_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:6]
ArgumentError: Error #2068: Invalid sound.
 at flash.media::Sound/play()
 at LetsChant_fla::MainTimeline/onClickPlayHandler()[LetsChant_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:31]

And in the ('yourMp3FileName.mp3')); I should type the AS Linkage or the file name?

Comment: if you have the sound as want to use as linkage, you can just replace this:

var mySound:Sound = new mySound1(); and forget the load method

Comment: That is the code I am using and still an  error comes..

Line 8 | 1151: A conflict exists with definition of mySound in namespace internal

Comment: could you update your question adding your latest version of code?

Comment: I want it to loop 9999 times, I dont want it to start from the last position, I want the normal volume, and I want AS Linkage, I didn't understand what you said.

Comment: That's interesting, your question is how about to add music, if you test my answer will be possible to add music using your AS Linkage. If you want normal volume, to loop 9999 times, it's part of your scope and logic, you need to define it. Or open different questions concerning each topic.

Comment: Ah, I just used the Stop/Start in the frame sound.